# Echoing output by using mysqli

Tags: php

I'm getting an Notice: Undefined offset: 0 error when I try to output every row from database table. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ($row[$i]); //output:  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\helloworld.php on line 19
            $i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you using fetch_assoc, so the keys are not numeric

Comment: why don't you use fetch_array()

Comment: fetch_array() will give me  Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\helloworld.php on line 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this it may help you

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                foreach($row as $row_val)
                {
                  print($row_val); 
                }
                //or instead of foreach direcly use print_r($row);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if it fulfills your requirement then accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

`$row` is created each time and brings back one row of data from the database - there is no need to increment it - nor will it ever have an index of more than zero - unless your query uses column names or aliases that are numeric. It is simply a single row from the database and with each iteration of your while loop, it will be the next row.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ($row); 
            //output:  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in 
            // C:\wamp\www\helloworld.php on line 19
        }
    }
```

The difference between `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_array` is simple. When you fetch_assoc, it will return the row with the indexes of the columns you are selecting (or their aliases if you use them) while fetch_array will simply return you an array that is numerically ordered.

Comment: I see, but how should the code look like then? I tried your code, and I got the error. Notice: Array to string conversion.

Comment: I missed the `$row[$i]` in the first copy of your code. Would you like to try what it is now?

Comment: Where do you have to define $i ?

Comment: You don't define `$i` - you don't need it. `$row` is a new array with each loop of the `while` statement.

Comment: this code works, but printf has to be changed to print_r I wonder why.

Comment: I always use print_r for testing, not ever really used printf - assumed it would work :)

Answer (score 1):

fetch_assoc does not return row number index it returns column name as index.

try this code

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo $row['column_name'];
}
```

Edit:
For echoing all column names and values :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   foreach($row as $key  => $value){
       echo 'Column Name : '.$key.' => Value: '.$value .'<br>';
   }
}
```

Comment: How can you do that with every column_name there is in the table?

Comment: for example, if your table has a column which name is id, you can echoing by $row['id'] in while. If you want to echo all column in the table you can write foreach block in the while block something like this while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){foreach($row as $key => $value){ echo 'key: '.$key .' value : '.$value; } }

Answer (score 1):

In your code, using `fetch_assoc()` instead of `fetch_array()` is not only the issue. You were using `$i=0` and increment it till the `number of rows fetched`. And then using it for retrieving `column`. That is you are printing first column of first row, second column of second row, third column of third row etc. Then if the table has just 3 `columns` and the select query return 10 `rows` of data, the remaining 7 rows will result invalid columns in your loop and will result undefined index error.

You can get all the fields by using `foreach`

Try this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'databasename');
$query = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
           while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
               echo $value.', '; //output:  Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\helloworld.php on line 19

        }
    }
```